# How do I unlock new outfits for my Mii?

Tags: rustys-real-deal-baseball

I have been playing a lot of this game and bought a few different mini-games now.

I noticed, however, that I haven't managed to unlock any new outfits for my Mii.

How do I get new outfits?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To unlock most new outfits for your Mii avatar, you need to get A Ranks or higher in the Hi-Score Derby modes.

Here's a list of the outfits and their requirements:

- **Basic Uniform**: Get an A Rank in Bat & Switch's Hi-Score Derby A
- **Business Suit**: Get an A Rank in Bat & Switch's Hi-Score Derby B
- **Caveman Suit**: Get an A Rank in Gear Games' Hi-Score Derby A
- **Farmer's Outfit**: Get an A Rank in Drop & Pop Hi-Score Derby B
- **Football Uniform**: Get an A Rank in Volley Bats's High-Score Derby B
- **Kung-Fu Outfit**: Get an A Rank in Cage Match's Hi-Score Derby A
- **Manager's Jacket**: Get an A Rank in Gear Games' Hi-Score Derby B
- **Martian Outfit**: Get an A Rank in The Aim Game Hi-Score Derby A
- **Ninja Suit**: Get an A or A+ Rank in Bat Master
- **Pinstripe Uniform**: Get an A Rank in Feel the Glove Hi-Score Derby B
- **Pro Ump Outfit**: Get an A Rank in Make the Call's High-Score Derby A
- **Rusty Slugger Jacket**: Purchase all 10 of Rusty's games
- **School Uniform**: Get an A Rank in Quick Catch Hi-Score Derby A
- **Shorts Uniform**: Get an A Rank in Make the Call's High-Score Derby B
- **Space Suit**: Get an A Rank in Feel the Glove Hi-Score Derby A
- **Sweat Suit**: Get an A Rank in Cage Match's Hi-Score Derby B
- **Tropical Shirt**: Get an A Rank in Volley Bats Hi-Score Derby A
- **Western Outfit**: Get an A Rank in Drop & Pop Hi-Score Derby A
- **Workout Set**: Get an A Rank in The Aim Game Hi-Score Derby B

[Source](http://www.gamefaqs.com/3ds/726732-rustys-real-deal-baseball/cheats)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

What you need to do to get costumes for your Mii in Rusty's Real Deal is by getting an A or and A+ in each High Score Derby of the games. And I believe you unlock another outfit when you buy every single game.